# Remote Desktop Connection with MSTSCLib

Tags: c#, .net, remote-desktop

I'm trying to code a Remote Desktop Application using C# .NET.

I followed some examples (listed below) and created a Windows Form, added references to MSTSLib, added Microsoft Terminal Service Control to the Form and code the following behavior:

```
namespace RDConnector
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    
        const string server = "55.55.55.555";
        const string userNameBase = "username";
        const string passwordBase = "password";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                rdClient.Server = server;
                rdClient.UserName = userNameBase;    

                /*IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdClient.GetOcx();
                secured.ClearTextPassword = passwordBase;*/

                rdClient.AdvancedSettings8.DisplayConnectionBar = true;
                rdClient.AdvancedSettings8.ClearTextPassword = passwordBase;
                rdClient.AdvancedSettings8.EncryptionEnabled = -1;                 

                //// Start connection
                rdClient.Connect();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Status + " + rdClient.Connected.ToString());

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception ocurred: " + Ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it isn't working, the Connection status after calling `rdClient.Connect()` is 2 (0 before calling it), but nothing happens. I also ran the Example 1 and it doesn't work.

I'm using Windows 7 - 64 bit and Visual Studio C# Express. Visual Express Edition doesn't have a X64 compiler, Could be the problem related with that?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Examples:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RemoteDesktop_CSharpNET.aspx
2. [Running COM component controls on multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198725/running-com-component-controls-on-multiple-threads)

Comment: If this helps, I run the same program on windows7-x64 but compiling for x86 from VisualStudio and it works.

When connected, then rdClient.Connect is 1, 0 when disconnected

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine.The problem might be in server name. you can try by using {{ MachineName.DomainName }} instead of IP address.

Comment: was this ever answered? I am in the same boat now

Comment: @DanielWilliams This answer is my problem too.You guys have found any solution for that? I coded project, and run smoothly, but rdClient.Connected = 2. So confusing. Is there another lib for RDP connection?

Comment: @Klaus78 I set Platform target to x86 in my windows 10 64x. but still rdpClient.Connected = 2. Where is the problem? I have added "Microsoft Terminal Service Client Control version 1" from "COM Component" in visual studio.

Comment: @Klaus78 I see many "Microsoft RDP Client Control" in "COM Coponent" section. What are those? Are they useful for RDP Connections?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem at last. When you want to choose COM Components, just select "Microsoft RDP Client Control - version x". I choose the 8 version that works perfectly for me.