# UI Thread locking when loading data in background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, com

I have an issue with loading data into a COM object in a background thread.

I have some files that are taking a long time to load and when this happens my application locks up and becomes unusable.  Because of this I am trying to load the data in a background thread, `BackgroundWorker` object.

I traced into my code and placed a generic `Thread.Sleep()` in code behind for my Usercontrol that is loading the file.  I am able use the application during the `Sleep()` call but when I replace the `Sleep()` call with my `LoadFile()` call it locks the UI thread.

Here is the simplified version of the code that I am calling:

```
private void CurrentDocumentChangedEvents()
{
    //fire event for native file viewer

    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    gridView1.Focus();          
}

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Call to UserControl to load the file selected.
    LoadFileForViewing(filePath);
}

public void showFile(string filePath)
{
    //Method inside UserControl that loads my selected file
    Thread.Sleep(10000);

     //axoixctrl_Viewer.ViewFile(false, filePath);
}
```

axoixctrl_Viewer is the COM object that is loaded into my Usercontrol.  The usercontrol lives in the UI thread, it is initialized when the Form Loads.  Is the problem related to creating the COM object on the UI thread or is my threading wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Probably an STA issue - where your COM object executes all its methods on the main thread - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/804968/5427

Comment: The posted code is fine. Can we see the contents of `LoadFileForViewing`?

Comment: When is showFile being called? Not sure cause you didn't show that part of the code, but presumably you'd call it after your BackgroundWorker completes. I believe by default there's a stub for it, RunWorkerCompleted. Also, are you sure there isn't a typing mismatch when you're calling your COM function? You said the thread locks so this may not be of use, but try wrapping some of your problem code with try catch and see if you can spot anything off.

Comment: Only thing LoadFileForViewing() does is a simple File.Exist() check to make sure the filePath exists before sending the sting to showFile() inside the Usercontrol

Comment: The call to `axoixctrl_Viewer.ViewFile` is being invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: @morechilli - yeah, as soon as COM is mentioned....

Comment: Thanks all.  I am going to try something new based on all the comments

Comment: DoWork should not be calling a UserControl.... Separate GUI and non-GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I figured out that the reason I am having this issue.  It is because of a STA issue as posted by morechilli.  The COM object I am using can only be used Single Threaded.  Thanks for all the comments